# Coderbyte: Array Addition recursion

Tags: python

i need help understanding the logic behind this code submitted by another user

this is the question btw:

> Have the function ArrayAdditionI(arr) take the array of numbers stored
>   in arr and return the string **true** if any combination of numbers in the
>   array can be added up to equal the **largest number** in the array,
>   otherwise return the string **false**. For example: if arr contains [4, 6,
>   23, 10, 1, 3] the output should return **true** because 4 + 6 + 10 + 3 =
>   23. The array will not be empty, will not contain all the same elements, and may contain negative numbers.

```
def subsetsum(target, arr):
    if len(arr) == 0:
        return target == 0

    return subsetsum(target, arr[1:]) or subsetsum(target - arr[0], arr[1:])

def ArrayAdditionI(arr): 
    arr = sorted(arr)
    target = arr[-1]
    arr = arr[:-1]
    return 'true' if subsetsum(target, arr) else 'false'
```

i dont get how subsetsum() works.

Answer (score 1):

It's a recursive function that calculates all possible sums.

For example, in our sample array of `[4, 6, 23, 10, 1, 3]`, it begins by sorting it to become `[1,3,4,6,10]` and sets target to 23. Now if we follow the stack we see that

```
subsetsum(23,[1,3,4,6,10])
```

produces two different calls to `subsetsum`, namely `subsetsum(23,[2,3,4,6,10])` and `subsetsum(22, [2,3,4,6,10])`. This idea models the concept *if the sum exists, then it either uses the first element of the array, or it does not.* The first expression models *the sum does not use the first element of the array* and the second models *the sum uses the first element of the array*.

The base condition is simple, if the array is empty, then I have no further calculations to do, so if the target is 0, then I have found a sum contained within the array. For example, if I had called `subsetsum(1,[1])` it would produce a call to `subsetsum(0,[])` - I hope you can see why that would be a solution and to `subsetsum(1,[])` - which is obviously not a solution.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: which part is confusing you?